# Is iteration order over an enum deterministic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I am using the `aenum` library.

```
from aenum import Enum as Aenum

class Availability(Aenum):
    _init_ = "value string"
    PART_TIME = 1, "Part-Time"
    FULL_TIME = 2, "Full-Time"
    BOTH = 3, "Both"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.string

for value, string in Availability:
   print(value)
   print(string)
```

Empirically it seems to go in order of definition but I was curious if this was guaranteed.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? If it's not documented, it's presumably not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aenum.Enum` is [described](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/) as

> a Python stdlib Enum-compatible data type

and the stdlib `enum.Enum` is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum) as

> Enumerations support iteration, in definition order

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ethanfurman/aenum/blob/master/aenum/doc/aenum.rst) on Github:

> Enumerations support iteration. In Python 3.x definition order is used; in Python 2.x the definition order is not available, but class attribute `_order_` is supported; otherwise, value order is used if posible, otherwise alphabetical name order is used.